# Uploadify and back end script error messages

Tags: jquery, ajax, uploadify, custom-errors

Is there anyway to modify the queue item's message if there is an error in the back end script of uploadify.php? See mock-up below.

[image: pre-upload]

[image: custom error on queue item]

The first (gray) image will display completed even if there is a validation error in the back end script. This is a bit misleading. I would like it to look like second image above if possible. I've managed to get something close but I'm thinking it might not be the best solution, this is what I have so far:

```
...
'onComplete' : function( event, ID, fileObj, response, data ) {

if ( 1 != response ) {

$( '#image-upload' + ID ).addClass( 'uploadifyError' );
$( '#image-upload' + ID + ' .percentage' ).text( ' - Upload Error' );

}

}
...
```

Thanks for any and all help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key was to returning FALSE with the onComplete event which allowed me to re-write the contents of the .percentage DIV.

My back end script will return 1 if everything is cool which allows onComplete to fire it's default function.  If everything is not cool then a string is returned for the specific type of error.  That then gets entered into the .percentage DIV.

```
'onComplete' : function( event, ID, fileObj, response, data ) { 

                   if ( 1 != parseInt( response ) ) {

                         $( '#image-upload' + ID ).addClass( 'uploadifyError' );                                    
                         $( '#image-upload' + ID + ' .percentage').text( ' - ' + response );

                         return false;

                    }               
                }
```